# Simple string manipulation in Scala

Tags: string, scala

Suppose I need a function `stripBang(s: String): Option[String]`:

- if `s` is either null or empty return `None`
- if `s(0) == '!'` return `None`
- otherwise return `Some(s.tail)`

I am writing the function as follows:

```
 def stripBang(s: String) = Option(s).flatMap(PartialFunction.condOpt(_) { 
    case s if s.nonEmpty && s(0) == '!' => s.tail
 })
```

It seems to work but looks clumsy. How would you suggest improve it?

Comment: Converting to an option just so you can check it isn't null is a bid weird. Good style is to avoid nulls, but if you have them, there's nothing wrong with just comparing to null.

Comment: Also, your test for '!' is in contradiction with the spec you give earlier, and you probably want to return Some(s.tail) (since in other cases you return None)

Comment: @Paul You are right about returning `Some(s.tail)`. I am fixing the spec. Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not `startsWith`?

```
def stripBang(s: String) = Option(s).flatMap(str => if (str.startsWith("!") || str.isEmpty()) None else Some(str.tail))
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot about `startsWith`.

Comment: In REPL you can enter some value and hit tab, it will show all the methods for this type, choose some method and hit tab and it will show you it's signature.

Answer (score 4):

So many complicated answers! I would suggest this simple function, which clearly exposes the intent:

```
def stripBang(s: String): Option[String] =
  if (s != null && s.nonEmpty && s(0) != '!') Some(s.tail)
  else None
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with an implicit class:

**Implementation**

```
implicit class StripBang(s: String) {
  def stripBang = s match {
    case null => None
    case "" => None
    case s : String if s startsWith "!" => None
    case s : String => Some( s )
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
scala> "test".stripBang
res3: java.io.Serializable = Some(test)

scala> "!test".stripBang
res4: java.io.Serializable = None

scala> "".stripBang
res5: Option[String] = None

scala> val s : String = null
s: String = null

scala> s.stripBang
res6: java.io.Serializable = None
```